# How to check if certain Node Attribute has Children? If there is none, returns "false". Otherwise, returns "true"

Tags: c#, xpath, treeview, linq-to-xml, xmltextreader

Here's the xml file I am trying to check if it has child nodes triggered by TreeView SelectedNode on `Database` node:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
    <Profile>
        <node text="California" tag="a" imageindex="0">
            <node text="Database" tag="b" imageindex="1">
                <node text="Type" tag="MySQL Server" imageindex="-1" />
                <node text="Name" tag="alona" imageindex="-1" />
                <node text="Connection" tag="Server=localhost; UID=root; PWD= ????????" imageindex="-1" />
            </node>
            <node text="Company File" tag="c" imageindex="2" />
            <node text="Tasks" tag="d" imageindex="3" />
            <node text="Logs" tag="e" imageindex="4" />
        </node>
        <node text="New Orleans" tag="a" imageindex="0">
            <node text="Database" tag="b" imageindex="1" />
            <node text="Company File" tag="c" imageindex="2" />
            <node text="Tasks" tag="d" imageindex="3" />
            <node text="Logs" tag="e" imageindex="4" />
        </node>
    </Profile>
```

The above xml file is generated by the TreeView and the data like `California` and `New Orleans` are user defined including the children of the `text="Database"`.

Now, I just want to check if `Database` node has children?

Here's what I have so far and got lost with `SelectSingleNode`, both `TsmNewDb` property returns `true`:

```cs
    selNodeParentName = TvwPanel.SelectedNode.Parent.Text;
    selNodeName = TvwPanel.SelectedNode.Text;

    Save_Treeview_To_Xml xcf = new Save_Treeview_To_Xml();

    try
    {
        XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(xcf.xmlProfileComplete);
        XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNavigator node = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//Profile/" + selNodeParentName + "/" + selNodeName);
                
        if (node != null)
        {
            TsmNewDb.Enabled = false;
        } 
    }
    catch
    {
        TsmNewDb.Enabled = true;
    }
```

If you have better ways, please feel free to suggest your own code. I read `XmlTextReader` is a lot faster but haven't figured out how yet.

**UPDATE 1:** I am attempting to use now `Linq to Xml` but having issue with int var below `childrenCount` that returns 0 either `California` or `New Orleans` elements.

```cs
    selNodeParentName = TvwPanel.SelectedNode.Parent.Text; //tested result "California"
    selNodeName = TvwPanel.SelectedNode.Text;              //tested result "Database"

    Save_Treeview_To_Xml xcf = new Save_Treeview_To_Xml(); 

    XElement xmlComplete = XElement.Load(xcf.xmlProfileComplete);  //loaded successfully
    int childrenCount = xmlComplete.Descendants(selNodeParentName).Elements(selNodeName).Count();

    MessageBox.Show(childrenCount .ToString()); // result always 0

    if (childrenCount > 0)
    {
        TsmNewDb.Enabled = false; // TreeView ContextMenu button
    }
    else
    {
        TsmNewDb.Enabled = true; // TreeView ContextMenu button
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what's going on because you don't indicate what the value of `selNodeParentName` and `selNodeName` are. I assume they'd be something like `node[@text='California']` and `node[@text='database']`, respectively? Though if the result of `TsmNewDb.Enabled` ends up as `true` does that imply an exception was thrown?

But to answer your question; once you've found the element whose `name` attribute is `database`, you can use the SelectChildren method of XPathNavigator to query for its children: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.selectchildren?view=net-6.0

If you pass `String.Empty` as the value of both parameters, you will get an iteration of all child nodes (with any name and namespace). If there are no children, the iterator's `Count` property will be zero.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it appears to be a long shot procedure. I am looking at a straight forward `Yes or No` answer from the code. The reason is I will be using this as a method across my project. I am trying right now `Linq to Xml` approach. I will update my attempt here.

Comment: It's clear what your bug is now; it's the same as the original bug using XPath; in both cases you are querying for an element whose name is `California`, but that's not the element's name; it's the value of the element's `name` attribute; the element's _name_ is `node`.

Comment: Oh my goodness! I didn't see that! Yes, you are right I just verified it! I've been trying different approach but all failed. I've been messing around this for 5 hours already. Thank you thank you. Now, the challenge is how to get to the attribute.

Comment: Using the XPath code, you could try `XPathNavigator node = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//Profile/node[@name='" + selNodeParentName + "']/node[@name='" + selNodeName + "']");`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but there still some fixing needed. I was able to find a workaround but it is a long route. I am not sure if its worth posting here. I used `Linq to Xml`.